# How to solve org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException selenium grid 3

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am using selenium **3.2.0** standalone, chrome latest version and chrome driver latest version which is giving not able to connect exemption on running.
Issue is with chrome driver please help

`org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:`

my code look like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/WorkSpace/Econsys_Auto/Jarfiles/chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/WorkSpace/Econsys_Auto/Jarfiles/chromedriver.exe");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");

capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.XP);

System.out.println("*******");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
driver.get(baseUrl);
```

Comment: You're attempting to connect to a remote browser session. How is the node configured? Have you tried a local session?

Answer (score 0):

Got selenium 3.2.0 with chromedriver 2.28, but I got Win10.

Try this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");//use your path
            try{
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you please try again using Selenium 3.3.0 (which is released just now)

There was an issue in Selenium (versions previous to 3.3.0) which was preventing the actual reason for the new session failure from being relayed to the test. That explains why you are not able to identify the root cause.

This now stands fixed in Selenium 3.3.0 as part of [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/e6207a6345068a569d8f2f62bd269beaa66d3061) commit

Now coming back to the possible reasons why your tests are not spawning a chrome browser.

I notice that you are using

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/WorkSpace/Econsys_Auto/Jarfiles/chromedriver.exe");
```

in your test code.
This sets up the JVM argument `webdriver.chrome.driver` ONLY for the current JVM. The Grid and the node are running in a different JVM (remember you spawned them using `java -jar` command ?).

I would instead recommend that you add **"E:/WorkSpace/Econsys_Auto/Jarfiles/"** to your `PATH` variable. This is a one time exercise you would be doing on a "per machine" basis and this will ensure that Selenium finds the `chromedriver` binary's location (I think that's why your tests are failing and you should be able to confirm this, if you looked at the node's console logs)